# How to get the file has special symbols?

Tags: android, special-characters, filenames, filenotfoundexception

When I try to get a file named 1233%1111.png,I get File Not Found Error.I know it's because special symbol %.How can I solve this problem?
I just want to upload this image.
Now,I try to use uri to approach it and create a new file from this file.Then I upload the new file.

Comment: Can you share what code you are using to `get this file`? You may need to escape the character. `new File( "1233\%1111.png" );`

Comment: I will try tomorrow.I'm going to sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a 'File' variable, you can try with file.exists(), and handle it accordingly.

If you want to check the file name, you can get the filename (as String) and use contains("%"), for example

Comment: I want to update this file,but the file's filename like 1234%1111.png.It show s File Not Found Error.

Comment: What are you trying so far? Please, feel free to edit your question to expand it and clarify better, so the other users can help you better